# Measuring the number of pulses and updating the counter after a certain number of pulses have occured using Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, system-verilog, vlsi, xilinx-system-generator

I am trying to build a counter using Verilog which will update itself after a certain number of pulses have been detected. For example, if I am giving a 10kHz input, after every 10 pulses have been detected the counter will go up by one. I am trying to figure out how to do it, but I can't figure out the logic behind it. Can someone help me in that ?

I wrote the following code, but when I remove the comments part and run the code, it gives me errors, and if I run the code with those comments as it is, I get wrong output.

```
module decade_counter(en, clock, count, count_og);
input en, clock; 
output reg [3:0] count;
output reg [3:0] count_og; 
  always @( posedge clock)
    begin
      if(en) 
        begin
          
          if ( count>=4'd0 && count<4'd9)
          count<=count+4'd1;
              //begin
           if(count == 4'd9)
                count_og<=count_og+4'd1;
              //else
               //count_og<=4'd0;
              //end
              //break
        else
         count<=4'd0;
          
        end
      
      else 
        count<=4'd0;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  This Verilog code will have `count_og` increment once per every 10 `count`'s:

```
module decade_counter (
    input en, clock,
    output reg [3:0] count,
    output reg [3:0] count_og
);

    always @(posedge clock) begin
        if (en) begin
            if (count < 4'd9) begin
                count <= count + 1;
            end else begin
                count <= 4'd0;
            end
        end else begin
            count <= 4'd0;
        end
    end

    always @(posedge clock) begin
        if (en) begin
            if (count == 4'd9) begin
                count_og <= count_og + 1;
            end
        end else begin
            count_og <= 4'd0;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Consistent indentation is crucial to writing code that is easy to understand.

You could try to have both counters in the same `always` block, but I often find it simpler to separate counters into different blocks.

Your simulator likely gave you a compile error for the `break` statement.  That is only allowed inside loop constructs, such as `for` loops.